# EntityTooSmall when uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to my S3 bucket using multipart upload. I'm following the exact same code as found [here](https://github.com/apoorvam/aws-s3-multipart-upload/blob/master/aws-multipart-upload.go). The problem is, whenever it reaches the last part of my file, I get a `EntityTooSmall: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size` error.

Issue: S3's multipart upload restricts file part sizes to a minimum of 5 MB

Solution: S3 allows the last part to be less than 5 MB large

Issue: This **is** my last part. And it's not being recognized. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: `maxPartSize = int64(512 * 1000)` – This isn't 5 MB. `5 MB = 5 << 20`

Comment: @icza then how do you recon it's working?

Comment: I just pointed out something that is most likely an error in your code. Change `maxPartSize` to be `5 << 20` and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @icza's pointers, the code I've mentioned above is not quite complete. The error I was receiving had nothing to do with the last bit. Apparently, it's part of the `completeMultiPartUpload` function. That's where the error is being thrown.

**Details:** The `uploadPart` is taking my data, whatever my chunk size is, and storing it in a pool of some sort. The error is being thrown at the `maxPartSize`, being too small. Changing that to anything greater than 5 MB solved the issue.

Comment: The documentation isn't fully correct.  The minimum part size isn't 5 MB = 5 × 1000 × 1000.  It's 5 MiB = 5 × 1024 × 1024.  Not sure what you were going for with 512 × 1000.

Comment: I agree. After contacting the [author](https://github.com/apoorvam) of the code, it was [fixed](https://github.com/apoorvam/aws-s3-multipart-upload/commit/ea47201d5130871b73c245fb2279a33afcdb3884).